# Killing/Stopping duplicate Threads in Android

Tags: multithreading, android-activity, duplicates

I cannot seem to find an answer to this question. What I have is the following, I have an activity which spawns 8 threads to do certain things, these threads need to remain active when the activity is closed and that works. The problem I have is when I open the activity again it spawns another instance of the same thread.

I am using DDMS in eclipse to verify that multiple copies of the thread are being spawned, I also have a toast message that outputs the ID of the thread every second to verify that there are indeed two copies of the thread running.

So my question is, how do I avoid multiple instances of the thread from running or how do I kill the older instances?

An example of one of the threads is below.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            while(true)
            {  
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");    // This is where we read the global date and time into our string
                currentDateTimeString = df.format(new Date());

                DateFormat womm = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");                   // This is where we read the minute of the wait one minute into our string
                WOMMinString = womm.format(new Date());

                DateFormat womh = new SimpleDateFormat("hh");                   // This is where we read the hour of the wait one minute into our string
                WOMHourString = womh.format(new Date());

                DateFormat cds = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");                    // This is where we read the current day into our string
                currentDayString = cds.format(new Date());

                DateFormat cms = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");                    // This is where we read the current month into our string
                currentMonthString = cms.format(new Date());

                DateFormat cys = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");                  // This is where we read the current year into our string
                currentYearString = cys.format(new Date());

                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e1) 
                {
                    appendLog("Could not sleep the thread (Main 2) " + currentDateTimeString + "");
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Store the reference to the thread in an instance variable:

```
private Thread myWorker;
```

In `onResume()` check whether the thread is running and if not, create a new one and start it.

Be aware that Android has a very strict policy regarding power and memory consumption, so your application might be killed any time, including your threads. Furthermore, Activities should be able to be paused and stopped at any time. Make sure that your thread is properly stopped when the Activity is paused or stopped.

So the best way to do long-term computations is using a `Service` class instead of `Activity`. You still have to create distinct threads for your work but the lifecycle is a little bit more relaxed.

**References:**

- [Android Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)
- [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: My thread needs to remain active when the activity is closed, it is a background thread. So I cannot stop or close the thread. The problem is that when I re enter the activity I do not want two instances to be present.

Comment: Just create a separate `Service` class and start this service from your `Activity` class. In the `Service`, run your threads. This would be the right way to do it. A `Service` is independent from the `Activity`'s lifecycle. However, it will be killed as well, when the application is force-closed by the user or operating system.

Comment: The threads access too many variables that are declared in the activity, it will just bee too hectic to get that working, will first see if there is not another way.

Comment: @user1504215: If you use a local service, i.e. one that runs in the same process as your Activity, you could create a method in the service `doWork()` which will take your Activity as argument and spawns the threads. So access to the Activity instance is not a problem.
A local service example can be [found here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample).